# php plugin / include issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a plugin system for one of my apps but I'm having a bit of trouble.

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically add additional switch blocks to a switch statement using a plugin class.

Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do, does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

```
switch($_GET['section']){
    default:
        // code here
    break;

    case 'test':
        // code here
    break;

    $plugins->run('page');

}

class plugins {
    function run($section){
        if($section=='page'){
            case 'test2':
                // code here
            break;
        }
    }       
}
```

The case statement in the plugins class is what I'd like to be returned to the original switch statement. So in the plugin class I can add additional cases that can be included in the original switch statement.

So I think basically just wondering if its possible to dynamically add additional cases to the switch statement.

Comment: You can't do that. You should be rethinking your problem. Why not package the complete switch statement inside your plugin class and dynamically run that?

Comment: I'm really confused by this. What do you mean by "plugin"? And why is the `case 'test2':` by itself, outside of a `select`?

Comment: @ Whoever downvoted this, it is not a bad question.  It is imo a relevant and clear question about a bad idea :)

Comment: I've updated the question with a bit more info so hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better achieve what you are trying to do by using classes and inheritance.

http://www.monkeycancode.com/php/php-class-tutorial

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong syntax:

```
if($section=='page'){ // WRONG!
    case 'test2':
       // code here
   break;
}
```

You can do it like this:

```
switch ($section) {
    case 'page':
         switch ($whatever) {      
              case 'test':
                   // do something
              break;
         }
    break;

    default:
        // do default stuff
    break;
}
```

It is always a good idea to use `switch` instead of `if else`!